# How do I check how git was installed on OS X?

Tags: git, macos, github

I'm using a Mac that already has `git` installed, and I want to update the version. I'd like to know how git was originally installed so that I can update it using the same tool. I ran `brew list` and didn't see git listed, so I'm not sure where else to look.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: [tag:git] is preinstalled on a Mac.

Comment: [Is git pre-installed on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304100/is-git-pre-installed-on-macos-sierra#:~:text=macOS%20does%20come%20with%20git,by%20the%20'Apple%20Git'.&text=If%20git%20is%20installed%20using,%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fgit%20.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find git installed in your mac, you can try to run command

```
which git
```

to show directory that git located
in my mac it located

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Try it out, Thanks